# Where can I find any assay of common baking soda (for example Arm and Hammer or generic grocery store brands)?

Tags: elemental-analysis

I am looking for any assay of common baking soda, listing approximate percentages of impurities or trace elements for example potassium, boron, chloride, fluoride, etc.

For example my naive guess would be it's 98 percent sodium bicarbonate, with the remaining 2 percent consisting of potassium, chloride, aluminum, calcium, and so forth.  What are the percentages of each of these.

I just want some order of magnitude assay.
Not requiring super accuracy nor large sample size.

I didn't find results on the web.
Please direct me to any assay that would give me such estimates.

Comment: Sodium bicarbonate (also called sodium hydrogenocarbonate) is produced with a rather high degree of purity. Whatever its quality, the purity is always greater than $99.5$ %. The main impurities are calcium and chloride, which are both smaller than $0.01$%, after Merck catalog.

Comment: The only relevant source of such info is what the vendor ( or in some cases independent agency ) provides for the product. Baking purpose may generally involve improving additives.